# c# display number in datagrid with decimal separator

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, decimal

i bet im not looking well but I cannot seem to find the answer to the following question:

i have a Datagrid which will display multiple columns with numbers, some will be above the thousand however i cannot seem to get it to display a decimal separator, I'm saving the numbers as a decimal value but it wont display it.

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question :)

Edit: this is about showing it in a datagrid in Windows Forms

Comment: What technology is this? ASP.NET? WPF?

Comment: Sorry didnt mention, winForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn.format.aspx) property on your `DataGridTextBoxColumn`. The format you’re after is presumably `"N0"`, which shows the thousands separator but no decimal places.

```
 DataGridTextBoxColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
 textColumn.HeaderText = "My Numbers";
 textColumn.ReadOnly = true;
 textColumn.Format = "N0";
 text
```

**Edit**: If you want your numbers to always format consistently, irrespective of the culture of the machine on which the application is run, then you should set the `FormatInfo` as well.

> The [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) for the computer is used to determine the actual currency format. You can change the `CultureInfo` for a `DataGridTextBoxColumn` by setting the [`FormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn.formatinfo.aspx) property to a new `CultureInfo` instance constructed with an appropriate culture ID.

For example, if you’re in Germany and always want the thousands separator to appear as a period (e.g. `12.345.678`) rather than a comma (e.g. `12,345,678`), use:

```
 textColumn.FormatInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

You might achieve better consistency by changing the culture for the entire application by setting the [Application.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.currentculture.aspx) property on startup.

Comment: I have the impression that the OP needs 'decimal separator'. And by the way, we don't know the cultureinfo required.

Comment: I assume that the OP confused the term, and was referring to the _thousands separator_ (“some will be above the thousand”).

Comment: Thanks, this was it. sorry for not being clearer, and thanks for understanding what i ment!

Comment: What about DataGridView? I am using a C# DataGridView with a column of decimal for monetary value. How I can apply thousand separator format to it? Cause DataGridViewTextBoxColumn of DataGridView does not support Format property!

Answer (score 0):

For DataGridView, whose DataGridViewTextBoxColumn does not have the Format property, we need to set the format as follow:

```
var col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
var colFormat = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
colFormat.Format = "N0";
col.DefaultCellStyle = colFormat;
```